# How to read logs from Monolog in my application?

Tags: symfony, monolog

My Symfony application runs calculations based on a user's request. I'd like to send them an email as a response.

I have created a custom channel and handler in `config.yml`:

```
# config.yml
# ...
monolog:
    handlers:
        buildbot:
            level:    info
            type:     stream
            channels: [buildbot]
```

Now I write logs to it from various services:

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Services/BuildBot.php
$this->buildLogger->info('Fabricating robot shell');
```

In a service I want to email the requestor with log lines from the "buildbot" Monolog channel. How can I read the log lines?

Answer (score 2):

From a design perspective I don’t think that Symfony’s logger is the right tool to use for this task. In my opinion that logger is meant to log information about your application’s activities that may or may not be useful to you as the developer (or other kinds of administrators).

Whereas in your use case the log is meant for the end user and doesn’t really contain application-level information  but request-level information. I would separate that.

My personal approach would be to create a simple service (that might even implement the logger interface) that accepts those messages, subscribes to the `kernel.terminate` event and sends the combined messages to the user in the end.

Anyway, if you really want to do this with Monolog, you should look into its handlers. [Here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#handlers) is a list of available handlers whereas [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/monolog.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html) are Symfony-specific examples on how to configure them. You probably have to write your own mailing handler because the packaged one assumes that there is a static recipient whereas you probably want the mail to be sent to the current user.